# Making a custom skybox for Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, adobe-illustrator, skybox

I'm struggling to find any simple/up to date tutorials on how to make my own skybox for Unity. I want the skybox to be cartoony/vector based so preferably I would like to make it in Adobe Illustrator.

How do I do this? Could anyone direct me to any tutorials? Also, are there any programs that allow you to upload an image that generates a skybox for you?

Thanks!

Comment: why were you "struggling" to find the doco dudester?  it's right there in the Unity documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may create a new "Skybox/6 Sided" material,  and asing it instead the default skybox material. It's the same principle, a cube with 6 images that correspond to each side "front, back, up, down, left, right".

Answer (score 1):

You have to generate a cubemap to have a skybox object, young padawan.
From the Unity Manual:
http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Cubemap.html

A Cubemap is a collection of six square textures that represent the reflections on an environment. The six squares form the faces of an imaginary cube that surrounds an object; each face represents the view along the directions of the world axes (up, down, left, right, forward and back).

Cubemaps are often used to capture reflections or “surroundings” of objects; for example skyboxes and environment reflections often use cubemaps.